# can't install Send2Trash python module

Tags: python, pip

been trying to install the Send2Trash module for python with pip, but so far with no success.
so i punched in `pip install Send2Trash` into the terminal and what i got was:

```
Collecting Send2Trash
  Using cached Send2Trash-1.3.0.tar.gz
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 377, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources.extern'

You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

unrelated note, i also tried to update pip and it just installed 7.1.0 again.
this is the first time using pip, so it might be a real newbe mistake...

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade pip with the command `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`.

If the upgrade is successful (a message will show), then install the send2trash package, again with the sudo command, as so `sudo pip install send2trash`. That should get the job done.

Comment: don't use `sudo` with pip

Answer (score 0):

As mulanLA mentions, your error is likely because you should upgrade pip. However, **you shouldn't be using `sudo` when upgrading pip**.

Once you've upgraded `pip` you may still get a `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/send2trash': Permission denied` message when attempting to install `Send2Trash`. To get around this install with the `--user` flag:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install Send2Trash --user
```